# How to fetch only the last approved version of a List Item O365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spservices, content-approval

I have enabled content approval for a custom list. And I have a html page where the requirement is to show all the approved items in the list using SPServices.  With content approval enabled, users with Read/Edit permission(except the author of list item) are able to see only the approved content. But the users with other Higher permission level are able to see the non-approved content as well.  Is there any solution available to show only approved content to all users?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options if you want to manage it within the list.

1. Edit view and Go to -> 'Filter'  -> Select 'Approval Status' column
   and enter 'Approved'(language sensitive).
2. If you want to manipulate via any code using this CAML filter to get specific items.

   `<Eq>
       <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' /> 
           <Value Type='ModStat'>'Approved'</Value>
   </Eq>`

   > **Note:** *ModerationStatus value* is **language sensitive** remember to translate and use correct word.

---

*Update*

**C#:**

```
foreach(SPListItem item in items)
{
  foreach(var itmversion in item.Versions)
  {
    if(itmversion.Level == "Published")
    {...}
  }
}
```

**Powershell:**

```
foreach($item in $ListItems)
{
  foreach($version in $item.Versions | ? { ($_.Level -eq "Published") })
  {...}
}
```

Comment: both the option will filter data based on the current approval status.  My requirement is to fetch the last approved version of a list item even if it is currently under pending approval status.

Comment: Update my answer to get item via code..

Answer (score 0):

You can do as suggested, create new view filter with 'Approval Status' is equal to 'Approved':
[image]

But Why are you want to achieve that?

By default, if you choose "Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)", with content approval enabled:

1.users with Read/Edit permission(except the author of list item) are able to see the last approved version of a List Item.

2.users (the author of list item) or with other Higher permission level are able to see the non-approved content.

If you configure that only show last Major versions for all users in SharePoint, that is to say no one can approve the document?